# Heroku with whitenoise not serving django staticfiles

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

How do I get heroku to serve my static files on my django project?

Ok, on a push to heroku, I get this message rlated to staticfiles:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        130 static files copied to '/tmp/build_48c64d55/staticfiles', 410 post-processed.
```

But when I go to my site, clear static files not being recognized and Network tab shows me:

```
GET https://pure-everglades-09529.herokuapp.com/static/style.css   404 Not Found
```

This is the content of my html referencing the css I cannot find:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

Here is the bottom of my settings.py which is configured just like everywhere says it should be like:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Here is higher up in my settings, I have added whitenoise dependencies as recommended everywhere:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Disable Django's own staticfiles handling in favour of WhiteNoise, for
    # greater consistency between gunicorn and `./manage.py runserver`. See:
    # http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
...
]
```

Lastly, here are my urls, where I added the static urls but only for my local env:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if 'Owner' in settings.BASE_DIR:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=setting
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it because I have DEBUG=True in settings? I set that to False as check but got a 500 error

Answer (score 1):

Apparently

```
# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]
```

needs to be

```
# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

staticfiles still created in correct location, probably because of VARIABLES
getting overwritten by

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```